# BX-Slider is not working

Tags: magento2.3, css, jquery, html, slider

I have implemented the BX slider to one of my module. After implementing the BX slider, I can see the script and CSS for BX-slider have loaded when i look into the developer tools. However, the Bx slider is not visible and also the functionality is not working on the frontend.

**I want to display like below:**

[image]

**But I'm getting as below:**
[image]

**Below are the code I'm using:**

**Template file:**

```
<div id="collapse" class="collapse prolist-compare-corosel">
    <div class="compare-arrow"></div>
    <div class="overslide" id="overslide">





     <section class="overallbx">
       <ul id="compare-items" class="product-items product-items-names bxfrcmp" data-bind="foreach: compareProducts().items">
                <li class="product-item"> 

        <div class="bxroundup">
                    <div class="bxcolumnup">
                        <div class="bxcardup">
                            <div class="visual">
                        <input type="hidden" class="compare-item-id" data-bind="value: id"/>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-post': remove_url}" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove This Item') ?>" class="action delete cancelclose remove-slide" >
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('&times;') ?></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="" class="imagechange">
                             <img data-bind="attr: {'src' : image_src}" alt="">
                       </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="products-info">
                                <p class="model-name"><a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: name" class="product-item-link productword"></a></p>
                                <div class="price-area rPrice">
                                    <div class="purchase-price">
                                        <div class="price">$29,999.99</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>            




    </li>
</ul>

    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.bxfrcmp').bxSlider({
            minSlides: 3,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideWidth: 960,
            pager: false,
            moveSlides: 1,
            touchenabled:true,
            infiniteLoop: false,
        });
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated!

After tried as suggested by **Ben Crook**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As this HTML is rendered via Knockout JS it's likely that your script is loading before the elements have rendered, to check that just add `console.log(jQuery('.bxfrcmp'))` to your script and see what it returns.

I would handle this adding a method to the Knockout script that initialises your slider, and use the [afterAdd](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements) event to call it.

You would end up with something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="compare-items" class="product-items product-items-names bxfrcmp" data-bind="foreach: compareProducts().items, afterAdd: initSlider">
    ...
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
...
initSlider: function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bxfrcmp').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 3,
      maxSlides: 3,
      slideWidth: 960,
      pager: false,
      moveSlides: 1,
      touchenabled:true,
      infiniteLoop: false,
    });
  });
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried as you suggested. At first, I have added the console.log(jQuery('.bxfrcmp')) and got the console data. For your reference, I have added the image at question. After that as you point out, I have added the initSlider function and got image at least. However, it shows some error. I have added the screenshot which has the error I got at question. Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Use owl carousel instead bx-slider. it is easy to use and manage the
>   code. When we develop projects we use

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="extrajs" template="Magento_Theme::html/extrajs.phtml" after="absolute_footer" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="extracss" template="Magento_Theme::html/extracss.phtml" after="absolute_footer" />
</referenceContainer>
```

> so we dont clean cache everytime whenever we modify/write code.